# sort an array after adding a new value

Tags: c#, .net

So i have to write this Algorithm that adds a value in an array and then sorts it again

i have to use a method called "compareTo" which returns the following values: -1, 0 and 1

if it returns -1 it means the object we are trying to add comes for the other object while comparing

if it returns 0 the items are on the same spot  (i don't understand this)

if it returns 1 it means the place of the item is behind that object in the array

how would i go about reshuffling the array i am really mindfucked haha, can anybody give me a tip in the right direction?

this is what my sort function looks like now

```
`  public void sortArray(NAW item)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
        {
            //comparing every object in array



            if (_nawArray[i].CompareTo(item) == -1)
            {
                //it needs to be in front of the object

            }

            if (_nawArray[i].CompareTo(item) == 0)
            {
                //it needs to be on the same spot as the object

            }

            if (_nawArray[i].CompareTo(item) == 1)
            {
                //it needs to be behind the object

            }
        }
    }


`
```

compare function

```
   public int CompareTo(NAW andereNaw)
        {
            // signal compare to Logger
            Logger.Instance.LogCompare();

            if (andereNaw.Naam == Naam && andereNaw.Adres == Adres && andereNaw.Woonplaats == Woonplaats)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                if (andereNaw.Woonplaats != Woonplaats)
                { // woonplaatsen zijn verschillend
                    return Woonplaats.CompareTo(andereNaw.Woonplaats);
                }
                else if (andereNaw.Naam != Naam)
                { // woonplaatsen zijn verschillend en namen zijn verschillend
                    return Naam.CompareTo(andereNaw.Naam);
                }
                else
                { // woonplaatsen en namen zijn gelijk
                    return Adres.CompareTo(andereNaw.Adres);
                }
            }

        }
```

items in the array

```
        NawArrayUnordered array = new NawArrayUnordered(20);
        array.Add(new NAW("Persoon 1", "Adres 1", "Woonplaats 1"));
        array.Add(new NAW("Persoon 2", "Adres 2", "Woonplaats 2"));
        array.Add(new NAW("Persona non grata", "Adres 3", "Woonplaats 3"));
        array.Add(new NAW("Persoon 4", "Adres 4", "Woonplaats 2"));
        array.Add(new NAW("Persoon 1", "Adres 5", "Woonplaats 1"));
        array.Add(new NAW("Persoon 2", "Adres 6", "Woonplaats 2"));
        array.Add(new NAW("Persona non grata", "Adres 7", "Woonplaats 3"));
        array.Add(new NAW("Persoon 2", "Adres 8", "Woonplaats 2"));
        array.Add(new NAW("Persoon 9", "Adres 9", "Woonplaats 1"));
        array.Add(new NAW("Persoon 10", "Adres 10", "Woonplaats 2"));
```

Comment: You should probably figure out first what the assignment is and what you're supposed to do. By the look of it, the array will _always_ be sorted because of your implementation, so there's no need to sort again after adding. What you should do, I think, is find the proper place for the item and add. And it's not clear _what_ exactly is your question.

Comment: ive edited the main question

Comment: So assuming your want to sort ascending (doesn't matter which, if descending just reverse the process), your `compareTo()` would return `-1` if `item` is smaller than the value compared to, `0` if equal, and `1` if larger? Am I correct?

Comment: Wait, this is different again. So `CompareTo()` really is a string comparer? It would be helpful if you translated those comments to English.

Comment: Still confused.  You mention 'reshuffling' the array.  I presume you mean resorting the array after adding an item?  Are there any constraints on memory usage, or the style of sort?  If not, then the easiest, but most memory and resource intensive is a double nested for loop copying into a second array. A better way would be to do your 'sorting' before you insert and then use Array.insert when you find the right spot.  You can do this if the input array is known to be sorted already.

Comment: it compares strings by the first letter and if its the same it takes the second word and compares that

Comment: I don't see how `CompareTo()` would return anything but `0`.

Comment: I think it works.. kinda.  I am guessing the CompareTo is being used in an object oriented fashion and `this.` is being left off

Answer (score 1):

I think you may use this code:

```
public static T[] AddItemToSortedArray<T>(T[] array, T item) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    var result = new T[array.Length + 1];
    var index = 0;
    while (index < array.Length && array[index].CompareTo(item) == -1)
    {
        result[index] = array[index];
        ++index;
    }

    result[index++] = item;

    while (index < result.Length)
    {
        result[index] = array[index - 1];
        ++index;
    }

    return result;
}
```

For simplicity I'm using `int` as `T`
Usage:

```
var array = new[] {6, 9, 11, 14, 19, 22, 23, 28, 45, 47};
var item = 31;
var result = AddItemToSortedArray(array, item);
// result would be {6, 9, 11, 14, 19, 22, 23, 28, 31, 45, 47}
```